# Send email only once when admin panel in WordPress is loaded

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have a plugin that sends me an email whenever my admin panel is loaded. Here is the code:

```
function restrict_admin() {
    if ( current_user_can('manage_options') ) {
        $admin_email = $wp_security_options['email'] ;
        $subject = 'WP Security ALert';
        $body = 'Hi there somebody logged into your wordpress site.';
        $headers = 'From: wpsecurity@wsoplugins.com';

        mail($admin_email, $subject, $body, $headers);
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_init', 'restrict_admin', 1 );
```

This code works fine, but the problem is that it sends me an email every time any page in the admin section is loaded. I just want it to send me an email once, when the admin has logged into the admin dashboard. How do I do this?

Comment: Use add_action( 'wp_login', 'restrict_admin', 1 )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send email at `wp_login` action instead, and check if logged in user has admin privileges. I think that is a more logical and simple way to do what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Add a cookie after the first email is sent and then just check if the cookie is set you don't send another email.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE["sentmail"])) {
$admin_email = $wp_security_options['email'] ;
$subject = 'WP Security ALert';
$body = 'Hi there somebody logged into your wordpress site.';
$headers = 'From: wpsecurity@wsoplugins.com';

if (mail($admin_email, $subject, $body, $headers)) { setcookie("sentmail", "sent"); }

}
```

This is a session cookie ... so it will be deleted when you close the browser. You might want to delete it on logout if you want an email for multiple logins from the same client.